# How to deploy Xcode to multiple devices without connecting computer

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to deploy app to multiple devices in Xcode. I know how to deploy app to single device with connecting computer. But I wonder how to deploy the app to multiple devices? Is it possible to deploy app without connecting computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use tools like [TestFlight](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/) or [Fabric](https://get.fabric.io/)